# Get next Hannukah date in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I am trying to find out from today's UTC date the date of the next Hannukah.
I already found that C# has `HebrewCalendar` class and I was able to get the current Jewish date with `GetYear()`, `GetMonth()`and`GetDayOfMonth()`. But don't really know how to work with this information to get the Jewish date that is gonna happen next for the current date.

Hannukah is dated on 25th of Kislev (3rd month in Jewish calendar).

Comment: "to get the Jewish date that is gonna happen next for the current date". You mean that you need the Hebrew date of the next (upcoming) Hannukah?

Comment: There is no built-in way in `HebrewCalendar` class to get these dates as far as I know.

Comment: @haim770 that is exactly what I need

Comment: BTW, isn't these dates _can_ be change by Jewish community? Has it certain dates? AFAIK, Hanukkah is not a public holiday in United States or any other countries. Maybe saving all start dates of Hanukkah in a custom database table is a better option instead of try to calculating it programmatically? I don't know, honestly..

Comment: @SonerGönül For what I know these days won't get changed by jewish community, I am already counting many other holidays and it would be really inconsistent to add to the database just Hannukah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@DmitryBychenko's answer is fine, although if you don't want to loop, you can also calculate it:

```
var calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
var result = DateTime.UtcNow;
if(
        calendar.GetMonth(result) < 3
    || (calendar.GetMonth(result)==3 && calendar.GetDayOfMonth(result)<25)
  )
   result = new DateTime(calendar.GetYear(result), 3, 25, calendar);
else
   result = new DateTime(calendar.GetYear(result)+1, 3, 25, calendar);
```

If you are under 25/3 on the `HebrewCalendar`, use this year, else use next

Result is also 7 Dec 2015 in the gregorian calendar

If (as per the comments) you don't want those *pesky* `if` statements for some reason, you could do something like:

```
var calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
var result = DateTime.UtcNow;
var addYear = (calendar.GetMonth(result) < 3 || (calendar.GetMonth(result)==3 && calendar.GetDayOfMonth(result)<25)) ? 0 : 1;
result = new DateTime(calendar.GetYear(result) + addYear, 3, 25, calendar);
```

I don't think this helps readability but there you go

Answer (score 4):

As it was suggested on Twitter, here's a [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) solution:

```
// As of 2.0, it will be CalendarSystem.HebrewCivil
var calendar = CalendarSystem.GetHebrewCalendar(HebrewMonthNumbering.Civil);
var today = SystemClock.Instance.InZone(DateTimeZone.Utc, calendar).Date;

var thisHannukah = new LocalDate(today.Year, 3, 25, calendar);
return thisHannukah >= today ? thisHannukah : thisHannukah.PlusYears(1);
```

Alternative for the last two statements:

```
var year = today.Month < 3 || today.Month == 3 && today.Day <= 25
    ? today.Year : today.Year + 1;
return new LocalDate(year, 3, 25, calendar);
```

If we go ahead with [feature request 317](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/317), this could be much simpler. For example:

```
// Putative API only! Doesn't work yet!
MonthDay hannukah = new MonthDay(3, 25, calendar);
var nextHannukah = hannukah.NextOrSame(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

Eh, just *looping*? Testing `date` one by one starting from, say, `DateTime.Now`?

```
  HebrewCalendar calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
  DateTime result = DateTime.Now;

  for (DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date; ; date = date.AddDays(1)) {
    if (calendar.GetDayOfMonth(date) == 25 && calendar.GetMonth(date) == 3) {
      result = date;

      break;
    }
  }
```

it returns `result == 7 Dec 2015`?

Comment: 7 Dec 2015 is indeed the first day of Hannukah 5776

Comment: Seems fine but I was thinking about a way with not so many if statements